# Geometry Nodes: Points and Vectors

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

i want to create lines (edges) connecting the vertices of two grids (what i'm really trying to do is have an array of parallel vectors) with geometry nodes.

[image: two grids converted to points]

I thought i could

1. take a grid and convert to points
2. instance and move it (set position)
3. Get the position of each point
4. subtract the positions of the two grids
5. be done

But somehow i cannot find a way to convert points to vectors and vice versa
[image: Geometry Nodes Setup]

I think i am a little bit confused that a geometry of points is handled differently from a list of vectors (if there is something like that in geometry nodes). After all a point is just a set of 3 coordinates - i.e. a vector.

Also blender shows that the output of vector math/subtract is not compatible with the curve line input ( i guess it doesnt like having more than one vector as input, right?)

I guess that one implicit question is: how can i handle a list or array of vectors in geometry nodes?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you grids have the same number of x/y vertices,  you can connect them like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the "Field at Index" and Index every second by applying the modulo helped. With indexing you can also calculate the vectors.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to create an array of parallel (and equal length) lines is the following:

[image]

1. Extrude the vertices of a grid in one direction with `Extrude Mesh`.
2. Remove the excess geometry with `Separate Geometry`.