# Geometry Nodes plant: How can multiple points be moved to multiple target points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using curve lines instanced on points coming from curve circles with various resample amounts, I'm trying to make small stems that connect each leaf (not pictured) to a larger stem:

[image]
[image]

However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to set the position of the leaf stems to their respective larger stems. Instead, the result goes to a single point:

[image]

Whereas the ideal result would look something like this (please forgive the hand-placed edges for demonstration):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would have to do here is to capture the positions and the index of the endpoints of the splines at which you instantiate the further curves.

Then you can comfortably query the original position of these points and use them as target position for your curves.

So you first store position and index with `Capture Attribute` into the geometry, and then query these values again with `Sample Index`.

Like this (simplified):

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the efficient solution I was almost certain was possible yet was failing to work out. Many thanks- this logic is very educational and useful.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be nice to find a solution for moving points to multiple targets based on a specific index, here is the solution for this specific case using a different method.

Instead of moving one of each curve line's points to another indexed point, first a second curve circle was created:

[image]

And then the circle at the base was scaled down to .0001 and connected to the other one via the setup outlined here:
[Geometry Nodes: Points and Vectors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270449/geometry-nodes-points-and-vectors)

resulting in the desired outcome:

[image]

[image]